# Sequence of functions $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin nx}{1+nx}$ converges to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, sequence-of-function

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of functions with $f_n : [a,\infty) \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f_n(x) = \frac{\sin nx}{1+nx}$, for all $x \in [a,\infty)$ and $n \in \Bbb N$. Show that $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f(x)=0$ on $[a,\infty)$.

**attempt:**
Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x \in [a,\infty)$ be arbitrary. Choose $n_0 \in \Bbb N$ with $\frac{1}{n_0} < \frac{\varepsilon |x|}{1+\varepsilon}$ such that for all $n \in \Bbb N$ with $n\ge n_0$, we have
\begin{align*}
|f_n(x)-0| = \left|\frac{\sin nx}{1+nx}\right| &\le \frac{1}{|1+nx|} \\ 
&\le \frac{1}{n|x|-1}  \\
&\le \frac{1}{n_0|x|-1} \\
&< \varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Hence, $f_n \to f$ pointwise on $[a,\infty). \qquad \qquad \Box$

Does this correct?
I have a little bit confuse since the number $a$ given in the problem above is doesn't clear that it whether a negative or a non-negative number anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number $a$ must be positive; otherwise, the problem makes no sense.

Note that\begin{align}\frac1{n_0|x|-1}<\varepsilon&\iff n_0|x|>1+\frac1\varepsilon\\&\iff n_0>\frac{\varepsilon+1}{|x|\varepsilon}.\end{align}Other than that, what you did is correct.

Comment: Why if $a \le 0$ implies the problem makes no sense, Sir?

Comment: The function $f$ will not be defined at all points of $[a,\infty)$.

Comment: What does it mean? If $x≤0, f" undefined on $[0,\infty)$ ??

Comment: I did not write that. What I wrote was that if $a\leqslant0$, then $f$ not defined at all points of $[a,\infty)$. That's so because, if $a<0$, then points of the form $-\frac1n$ (at which $f$ is undefined) belong to $[a,\infty)$.

Comment: "at which $f$ is undefined". What is $f$ here? I'm confusing at here and didn't clear yet because $f$ is no formula, it is only $f:=f(x)=0$ for $x \in [a,\infty)$.

Comment: Do you mean $f_n$ instead of $f$?

Comment: Yes, I do. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your answer and time anyway.